# Создание xml-элементов средствами java и их стилизация

Tags: java, android, xml

Ситуация такая: есть пустой LinearLayout и есть два EditText.
После нажатия на кнопку создаётся новый RelativeLayout внутри уже существующего LinearLayout. К этому RelativeLayout применяется стили:

```
RelativeLayout rl = new RelativeLayout (new ContextThemeWrapper (this, R.style.relative));
LinearLayout ll = findViewById (R.id.content);
    
ll.addView (rl);
```

И тут все отлично. Но когда я добавляю в созданный RelativeLayout новую кнопку:

```
Button btn = new Button (new ContextThemeWrapper (this, R.style.relative_button));
rl.addView (btn);
```

Стили не применяются к этой кнопке!
Как мне решить эту проблему?

Comment: А появляется ли какая-то ошибка? Если да, то какая?